# How to tell google that 2 different domains are for the same website

Tags: seo, google, language

I have a website which is in Arabic language, I want to make an English version of my website, but here is the problem:

The English version of the website has a TOTALLY different domain than the Arabic one.

Is there a way to tell that to google ? I am afraid if I didn't tell google, they may think that the contents of the English version are duplicated, and reduce my rank.

Thanks

Comment: As covered [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77060/how-does-google-determine-duplicate-content-when-its-translated-into-different/77062#77062), Google doesn't consider sites that have been translated into different languages as the same site or duplicate content, providing the translation wasn't done automatically using their translation service. Therefore you don't need to indicate this to them, however, you can use `hreflang` to convey this if you're still concerned (see the previous link about that too).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the hreflag meta tag, see https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077

Important to note that "each language page must identify all language versions, including itself."

So yours should look something like;

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.englishsite.com/somepage/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ar" href="http://www.arabicsite.com/somepage/" />
```

"You can specify multi-language URLs in the same domain as a given URL, or use URLs from a different domain."